# How can I implement real time data alteration in my .net mvc 4.5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show graph in my website. and I want the graph to be updated according to real time data changes. I can't call the server at certain interval of time as it will increase overhead on server. I want the chart to be updated only when some changes occurs on the server side which should be reflected on the client side.

I'm trying to make a real time website which can be changes as data changes on the server side.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I've searched on net but didn't find anything relevant and useful. After searching a lot I thought I should ask this question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are using asp.net 4.5 then you can use SignalR plugin in your project. it will create a socket connection between server and client side.
So you can send information to the client side at real time whenever any changes occur on server side.

You can find detailed information on following link

[tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: is signalR reliable ?

Comment: not 100% reliable that you will get notified on some event occurred on server side. but you can rely on this. you have to write logic to check if client received the notification or not so you can continue your logic accordingly.